# How do I change the boot partition from one drives partition to a different drives partition?

Tags: boot, grub2, backup, partitioning, administration

I have two hard drives each with one primary partition, each with their own Ubuntu 18.04 install

sda1 40gb

sdb1 512gb

The only purpose of sdb1 is to hold compressed backups of sda1
Normally the computer boots and operates from sda1.

What I am trying to accomplish (via SSH konsole) is to change the boot device from sda1 to sdb1, then issue a reboot so that when it reboots sdb1 loads its copy of ubuntu, next I can create a backup image of sda1 and store it as a compressed image file on sdb1, after creating the backup image I would then want to change the boot drive back to sda1.

The purpose of this exercise is to be able to create a backup image of sda1 while it is unmounted to sdb1 using nothing but SSH.

I am familiar with changing boot devices in bios, or booting from thumb drives to create backups, I am trying to accomplish my goal without any physical interaction with the computer. (I do have physical access in-case things go wrong)

I have attempted changing the UUID entry in /etc/fstab to point to the UUID of sdb1 but grub/fstab still loads sda1 on boot/reboot.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to do this via BIOS/EUFI using whatever API/ABI they provide; which will be hardware specific & unrelated to the OS (Ubuntu) you are using.  Anything on your fs (inc. /etc/fstab/) will only affect things after the system has already started to boot a drive, which doesn't meet your requirements; ie. it needs to be your hardware (bios/eufi).  Some devices (eg. hp & dell servers I have) provide a internal usb inside the machine which can be used as a boot device; if you machine has this - select (via bios/eufi) that device and modify the data on that to boot the wanted drive

Comment: Your backups are compressed, so I think it is not possible to boot any of them at all.

Comment: @guiverc if the data on a usb device can point to the drive that I want to boot, then why cannot I have drive sda1 point to drive sdb1 as what I am wanting to boot?

Comment: @mook765 the reason for two ubuntu installs, is so that both the backup and restore of sda1 can be performed while sdb1 is the active drive, this way sda1 is unmounted, creating a backup or restore to an active drive is not a good idea. I am not looking to boot a compressed image, they are only compressed for storage purposes. My main obstacle at this point is finding a way to put some sort of instructions on SDA1 that says "NO, go boot SDB1 instead) those instructions I assumed would be modifying /etc/fstab or grub

Comment: the usb-device I'm talking about is often called DOM, and can be a SDRAM card or other device (inc. usb).  It often has a 2GB limit which is plenty to bootstrap a system.  It is treated differently by the machine BIOS and is different to the external devices, and is hardware specific. Your device probably doesn't have it (consumer or low-end server) so it won't be of help to you.  You've now been offered two answers anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using EFI boot, you can temporarily set your next boot target using `sudo efibootmgr -n <boot number>`

First check the boot list using

```
$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network

$ sudo efibootmgr -n 4
BootNext: 0004
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

The change only affect the next boot, so after rebooting again it will revert to the original boot order.

*(BIOS setup from Xekon's post)*

For BIOS systems, the best solution is **grub-reboot** which allows a one time boot of a different grub entry.

First we must set some settings for grub so that it cooperates with grub-reboot:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
```

ctrl+x to save and exit

```
sudo grub-set-default 0
sudo update-grub
```

now upon boot, look at the grub entries, it is 0 based, for me I have:

```
0 Ubuntu
1 Advanced options for Ubuntu
2 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/sdb1)
3 Advanced options for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/sdb1)
```

so my default is 0 (Ubuntu on /dev/sda1) and 2 (Ubuntu on /dev/sdb1) is my other install of ubuntu on the second hard drive.

So doing the following while booted into /dev/sda1, will allow me to boot a single time into /dev/sdb1:

```
sudo grub-reboot 2
sudo reboot
```

Then I can perform my backup or restore on /dev/sda1, and then simply issue a sudo reboot, and be booted back into /dev/sda1

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the reply. The systems I am currently working on are BIOS, no EFI. Will try this the next time I need to do this on an EFI system.

Also thanks for the GRUB_DEFAULT=saved info, I will try out the grub-set-default command.

The solution of modifying the grub.cfg file and changing the UUID is working on my bios system, but its a hack so I appreciate the reply.

Comment: Actually @bernard-wei For a BIOS system instead of using grub-set-default, I just read about the command grub-reboot which should allow you to boot a different device only once similar to sudo efibootmgr -n <boot number>

I am researching it now and getting ready to test it out. This feature also requires GRUB_DEFAULT=saved

Comment: @xekon Cool, let us know if `grub-reboot` works. I don't have a bios boot system to try it out anymore, thanks.

Comment: It does work @bernard-wei I just tested it, and it works flawlessly, can you update your answer so that all the good information is in one post, see my answer below for stuff you can copy and paste.

Comment: @xekon, I've updated my original post with your nicely written steps for BIOS setup. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

For UEFI systems, see Bernard Wei post

For BIOS systems, the best solution is **grub-reboot** which allows a one time boot of a different grub entry.

First we must set some settings for grub so that it cooperates with grub-reboot:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
```

ctrl+x to save and exit

```
sudo grub-set-default 0
sudo update-grub
```

now upon boot, look at the grub entries, it is 0 based, for me I have:

```
0 Ubuntu
1 Advanced options for Ubuntu
2 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/sdb1)
3 Advanced options for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/sdb1)
```

so my default is 0 (Ubuntu on /dev/sda1) and 2 (Ubuntu on /dev/sdb1) is my other install of ubuntu on the second hard drive.

So doing the following while booted into /dev/sda1, will allow me to boot a single time into /dev/sdb1:

```
sudo grub-reboot 2
sudo reboot
```

Then I can perform my backup or restore on /dev/sda1, and then simply issue a sudo reboot, and be booted back into /dev/sda1

Answer (score 0):

If you have two or more Linux OSs installed you can change the boot partition by changing the UUID in /efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file:

1. List the UUIDs:

`sudo blkid |egrep 'ext4|EFI'`

`/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="5794351c-6f04-4564-a25f-6026ed8090af" TYPE="ext4"`

`dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="5636-6FB1" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition"`

`/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="2978fb8c-5a4d-4a71-9376-f6a6c9c3f9e8" TYPE="ext4"`

2. Update the UUID in the /efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file:

`sudo mkdir /efi`

`sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /efi`

`sudo sed -i 's/2978fb8c-5a4d-4a71-9376-f6a6c9c3f9e8/5794351c-6f04-4564-a25f-6026ed8090af/' /efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`